# How to position CSS <div>s without breaking?

Tags: html, css, background, position

I have 2 backgrounds that should be overlapping each other, and a container which should be overlapping those 2 backgrounds. I can't get this to work, the container gets pushed down even thought I specified a position.

CSS:

```css
body { 
  background:#1b1b1b;
  padding:0; margin:0;
  color:white; 
  text-align:center;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.map { 
  background:url(../images/map.png) no-repeat top center; 
  width:1280px; 
  height:335px;
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto; 
  position:absolute; 
}
.map-bg { 
  background:url(../images/map-bg.png) repeat-x; 
  height:336px; 
  position:relative; 
}
.stripe { 
  background:url(../images/stripe.png) repeat-x;
  height:35px; 
  width:100%; 
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:158px; 
}
#container { 
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
  width:924px; 
  height:100%; 
  text-align:left; 
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Essbee</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"  />
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="bg">
      <div class="map"></div>
      <div class="map-bg"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="stripe"></div>

    <div id="container">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
      <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you link to a page running this code with the images etc in?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want? like maybe a link to a picture? Because I put your code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7UaXN/ and I'm not sure whats wrong

Comment: How much of this is working?  Are your backgrounds overlapping one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is your HTML structure.  From what I can gather you want to have four elements rendered on top of one another, `.map`, .`map-bg`, `.stripe` and `#container`.  The way you have your HTML and CSS, this won't happen because those elements are at different levels in the tree.  What you should do is wrap everything in `.bg` and set all of their positions to `absolute`, and set their parent container `.bg` to `position: relative`.  It's also always a good practice to put non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;` in your empty elements, since many browsers will not render a completely empty block level element predictably.

```
<body>

  <div class="bg">
    <div class="map">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="map-bg">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="stripe">&nbsp;</div>

    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="content">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Updated CSS:

```
body { 
  background:#1b1b1b;
  padding:0; margin:0;
  color:white; 
  text-align:center;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.bg {
  position: relative;
}
.map { 
  background:url(../images/map.png) no-repeat top center; 
  width:1280px; 
  height:335px;
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto; 
  position:absolute; 
}
.map-bg { 
  background:url(../images/map-bg.png) repeat-x; 
  height:336px; 
  position: absolute; 
}
.stripe { 
  background:url(../images/stripe.png) repeat-x;
  height:35px; 
  width:100%; 
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:158px; 
}
#container {
  position: absolute; 
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
  width:924px; 
  height:100%; 
  text-align:left; 
}
```

Try that, you should see results more in line with what I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Because .map-bg is position:relative, it will push down #container.

Maybe what you want to do is move .stripe inside of .bg and set .bg to position:absolute.  That way, .stripe will be positioned under .map-bg (I assume this is what you want?) and #container will ride on top of all the background divs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a screenshot of what you're trying to do? As far as I can work out, you're trying to put a div over two other divs, but there's almost certainly a much better way of doing it than positioning everything absolute.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you don't have the class "bg" specified in your css, for one.